# Find Cl from Cp values

Tags: airfoil

i have a code of the panel method where I can calculate all the Cp values.
my job is to calculate the Cl from these Cp values, and I understand that to do that I have to integrate the Cp over the airfoil.
on the Xfoil manual I find that the program to calculate the Cl integrate the Cp in dx, where x=x*cos(alpha)+y*sin(alpha) where alpha is the angle of attack.
i have the information but I don't know how to do that on Matlab, someone can help me? thanks!

Comment: it's similar but I don't really know how to implement this approach in Matlab. someone can help me? because I know theoretically how to do but I don't know how I can calculate the integral of cp on the airfoil. thanks!

Comment: Matlab support/training is outside the scope of this site. You can try on stackoverflow.com, but the way your question is worded right now they probably won't help you either. What did your research to solve the problem on your own bring up, what have you tried so far, where exactly are you stuck?